# R package installation - R CMD check throws ERROR: Installation Failed

Tags: r, r-package

I'm having trouble getting a package that I have written to install (on a Windows 10 machine).
I'm running `R CMD build packagename` (no errors), then `R CMD check packagename_0.1.0.tar.gz` (or `R CMD INSTALL packagename`)

After a number of successful log entries, the output reads

```
* checking whether package 'packagename' can be installed ...Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-3.4.0/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL -l 
"C:/Work/parsimony_inapp/packagename.Rcheck" --no-html 
"C:\Work\PARSIM~1\packagename.Rcheck\00_pkg_src\packagename"' had status 1
 ERROR
Installation failed.
```

*00install.out* reports the error:

```
C:/MinGW/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o packagename.dll tmp.def fitch.o reorder.o -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-
4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-3.4.0/bin/x64 -lR
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-3.4.0/bin/x64/R.dll: file not recognized: File format not 
recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'packagename'
```

Oddly, I can install the package from GitHub using `devtools::github_install('path/to/package')`.

Advice I've found elsewhere doesn't help:

- [setwd() in Rprofile](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/117) - not present
- [Set R_WIN_NO_JUNCTIONS](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-from-R-CMD-check-td4672633.html) - no effect
- I've updated to the latest version of R (3.4.0), RTools (34) and Cygwin, and checked that my `PATH` environment variable contains (in order) `C:\Rtools\bin; C:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin; C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin; C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\x64`.
- I've tried [including and excluding](https://www.r-bloggers.com/rtools-and-cygwin-on-ms-windows/) `C:\cygwin64\bin` and `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` from the path, and have tried installations of Rtools with and without the Cygwin dlls, and have tried uninstalling Cygwin completely.

Comment: As a workaround I uninstalled the 64-bit installation of R; the 32-bit compilation worked fine.